# Empty list trouble with cursor

Tags: java, android, cursor, linked-list

I´ve a problem with my `List<String>`

```
List<String> werte = new LinkedList<String>();
if(c.moveToNext()){
        werte.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fragencount")));
}
String size = "" +werte.size();
tv.setText(size);
```

I want to add strings from my Cursor into a `LinkedList<String>()`. When I try `c.getCount()`, I get 13. 
When I try to read the size of my `LinkedList`, I get 0. I don´t understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `do-while` for adding all value in LinkedList

```
  LinkedList<String> werte = new LinkedList<String>();
  if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            werte.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fragencount")));
        }while(c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
String size = "" +werte.size();
tv.setText(size);
```